# Setting up redis in docker

Tags: docker, redis

i have a very old project (in zend framework 1 - php).

I´m trying to run it with docker, so far i have made good progresses, but I am a newbie in docker. I am facing and issue with redis, because in my project redis is expecting to be on "127.0.0.1:6379" but now in docker it has to be name of container and not IP anymore "redis:6379". Is it possible to use that IP address and not name of container?

I do not want to change it in the project, because of production version, which will be still running by the old way.

Here is my conf files, also tried to create redis.conf and mount it, but no progress so far.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ../:/var/www/master/eshopy
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - expando_network

  php:
    build: ./
    image: php-8.1-expando
    container_name: php-8.1-expando
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/master/eshopy
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ../../library:/var/www/master/library
      - ../library/vendor:/var/www/master/eshopy/vendor
      - ../frontend/library:/var/www/master/eshopy/frontend/library
      - ../admin/library:/var/www/master/eshopy/admin/library
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    networks:
      - expando_network

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.11.5
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: eshopy
      MYSQL_USER: expando
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: expando2023
    volumes:
      - ./my-custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my-custom.cnf
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - expando_network

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - expando_network

  redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    healthcheck:
      test: redis-cli ping
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - expando_network

  redisinsight:
    image: 'redislabs/redisinsight:latest'
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - expando_network

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
      - nginx
      - elasticsearch
      - redis
    networks:
      - expando_network

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - expando_network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    networks:
      - expando_network

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge 

  expando_network:
    driver: bridge
```

redis.conf

```
bind 127.0.0.1
port 6379
```

My php project calling redis like this:

```
public function __construct($extLoaded) {
        $this->extLoaded = $extLoaded;
        if ($extLoaded) {
            $this->redis = new Redis(); 
            $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); //not work
            $this->redis->connect('redis', 6379); //work
        }
    }
```

**Solution working for me:**

in my nginx i added new fastcgi_param

```
fastcgi_param PLATFORM docker;
```

and in my php files:

```
if (getenv('PLATFORM') == 'docker') {
  $this->redis->connect('redis', 6379);
} else {
  $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
}
```

Comment: You tried `extra_hosts`? also why you simply do not use the env variables to distinguish between your prod & dev envs.

Comment: @hassan extra_hosts already tried.. nothing changed.. tried to add  extra_hosts:
      - "redis:127.0.0.1"

Comment: The Redis `bind` option you show will make it unreachable from other containers; you can probably delete that `redis.conf` file entirely.  If the `127.0.0.1` address is hard-coded in your application and you can't change it, then you probably can't run it in Docker – that IP address almost always refers to the current container only, and you can't make it mean something else.